# Question closed? What happened to "on hold"?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I have just closed a question as "unclear", and it says "closed" in the title. I remember that it used to be "on hold" for a few days, reflecting the hope that OP could edit it, and then it would be reopened.

Was the wording changed? Or is it some special case or heuristic which guesses "probably will not be reopened"?

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77624499/509868)

Answer (score 20):

The "On Hold" label was [removed in 2019 due to the new Post Notices update](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/339700/241919). Quoting the announcement:

> #### Where did the "On Hold" label go?
>
> "On Hold" had been used to label recently closed questions. The idea was that this language would imply less permanence to the current state than "Closed". However, user research showed that this distinction was generally found to be confusing to users at all levels, and did not seem to have an effect on reopen rates. So we have removed this label. All Closed posts are now labeled as Closed but only the label has changed. Edits within the first five days will still put the question in the reopen queue.

Comment: @ingotangjingle Questions can be reopened, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions and https://stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions

Comment: @Progman Making this process clear might improve the opening process. I have been trying to get answers to what a close reason means for a long time, and this is the first mention of opening closed questions.

Comment: @ingotangjingle You have at this point submitted edits to re-open questions several times. The "Submit for review" box is unchecked by default, so this means you checked it. The explanation is right underneath the label and plainly uses the word "reopening." If you needed additional explanation, the `?` icon can be clicked.

Comment: @ingotangjingle Documenting processes is the purpose of the [FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251225/faq-index-for-stack-overflow). The site documentation will probably never be any close to spectacular so people have taken matters into their own hands.

Comment: @ingotangjingle exactly the opposite, the FAQ is way better than the site documentation.

Comment: @ingotangjingle Given set A is a proper superset of set B and A is not empty, do you believe that you can conclude that B is empty? This is what you are asking, and the answer is, "no." Also, near the **very top** of the FAQ it says, "For official guidance from Stack Exchange, visit the Help Center," (i.e. the documentation).